# Make multiple batches of maximum size, different sized objects

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am a software developer with a rather simple problem. I don't really know how to express it in mathematical terms - I'll just try to write it down:

I have multiple different files... let's say 20 files. Each file can have a very different size. Some are very big, some are rather small. Each file is smaller than 3MB though.

My task is to form batches of files that are all as close to 3MB in size, but not more. This has to do with certain transmission limits.

The end result must be the minimal amount of file-batches possible.

How would I go about this? My pragmatic approach would be to just sort descending by file size and then start stacking a batch until 3MB would be exceeded, then start the next batch.

But is this really the mathematically best approach?

Comment: This isn't a mathematical insight, but constraint satisfaction tools like Minizinc will solve this very quickly for the small number of files you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is called [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), and there is a vast literature on exact and approximation algorithms (see the bibliography on the Wikipedia page).

Answer (score 2):

Minimizing the number of batches is a typical NP-complete problem. I've seen it under the name 'Load Balancing', but a google-search did not give many results (although the German Wikipedia knows it). The very simple algorithm you proposed does not always yield an optimal solution. Consider the sizes 2, 2, 1, 1, where two batches would suffice but your method would require three. It is, however, a 2-approximation algorithm: If the minimum number of batches required is N, you will need at most 2N. Why? Say you use M batches. Assume for a moment that M is even; the other case is almost identical. The content of any two 'consecutive' batches that you created exceeds 3MB (otherwise, they would coincide), so that the total size S (sum of the sizes of all the files) must be at least (M/2)*3 MB. But then any partition of the files into batches of size at most 3MB needs to have at least M/2 batches.